# Getting a strange error with Johnny-five motors

Tags: node.js, arduino, johnny-five

I'm trying to get a motor to work with Johhny-five. I'm using an arduino and I copied the code and the wiring (mostly) from their website. The only thing I changed in the wiring was instead of using a diode to make sure 5V doesn't go into the emitter pin of the transistor, I just wired it straight to the motor, without using the breadboard. Problem is, I'm getting this weird error

C:\Users\simas\node_modules\johnny-five\lib\motor.js:721
  this.speed({
       ^

TypeError: this.speed is not a function
    at Timeout.Motor.stop [as _onTimeout] (C:\Users\simas\node_modules\johnny-five\lib\motor.js:721:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
PS C:\Users\simas\Desktop\motors>

I am not at all use why this happens, please help.

(btw the code I copied from the website was :

```
const {Board, Motor} = require("johnny-five");
const board = new Board();

board.on("ready", () => {
 // Create a new `motor` hardware instance.
 const motor = new Motor({
   pin: 5
 });

 // Inject the `motor` hardware into
 // the Repl instance's context;
 // allows direct command line access
 board.repl.inject({
   motor
 });

 // Motor Event API

 // "start" events fire when the motor is started.
 motor.on("start", () => {
   console.log(`start: ${Date.now()}`);

   // Demonstrate motor stop in 2 seconds
   board.wait(2000, motor.stop);
 });

 // "stop" events fire when the motor is stopped.
 motor.on("stop", () => {
   console.log(`stop: ${Date.now()}`);
 });

 // Motor API

 // start([speed)
 // Start the motor. `isOn` property set to |true|
 // Takes an optional parameter `speed` [0-255]
 // to define the motor speed if a PWM Pin is
 // used to connect the motor.
 motor.start();

 // stop()
 // Stop the motor. `isOn` property set to |false|
});
```

)

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this same issue as a result of using the [Adafruit Motor Shield V2 example code from the Johnny-Five documentation](http://johnny-five.io/api/motor/#directional-motor-via-adafruit-motor-shield-v2).

This appears to be an issue with the context bound to the `motor.stop` call when passing the function directly to `board.wait`.

To get around this issue, declare your own function within the motor instance context and pass it to the `board.wait` call in your `"start"` event handler:

```
 // "start" event fires when the motor is started
 motor.on("start", () => {
   console.log(`start: ${Date.now()}`);

   // Demonstrate motor stop in 2 seconds
   board.wait(2000, () => {
     motor.stop();
   });
 });
```

Comment: It seems the examples [here](http://johnny-five.io/examples/motor-l298-breakout/) are wrong also. `board.wait(5000, motor.stop)` should be changed to `board.wait(5000, () => motor.stop())`.

Comment: Yep! Unfortunately many (most) examples online suffer from this same issue.